Why is the passive used in this sentence?
戸惑う心を置き去りに、足は母さんの元まで、走っていく。
みんなを振り向きながら、手が勝手に、ひらひらと振られた。
"As I turned my face toward everyone, my hand waved on its own."
I don't think it's saying it like the characters is having other people wave at him? But it's his own action?
Why is passive used?

Is it too obvious? The subject of 振られた is 手 (cf. 手を振る). The hand is the one receiving the action of getting waved.

This is a 自発 ("spontaneous") usage of the reru-form. Instead of something like "My hand was waved", this sentence should be interpreted like "I found myself waving my hand" or "Before I knew it, I was waving my hand".

Why do we distinguish the spontaneous (自発) and passive (受身) forms?
Why is the passive form used in this sentence?
Is there a reason why the passive and the potential form are identical (at least for える/いる verbs)?

